# How to push elements to array inside async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, puppeteer

How to push elements in array inside async function (puppetteer)?

The page is structured into severel levels. Levels only appear by clicking on a link inside a cell-element with a specific ID.

I already achieved to select current shown ID's, push them into an array to loop through and click links inside elements with that ID to open next hirachy. 
After this I repeat this process, by loopin through the difference of the new selected array of ID's (old ID's + new ID's) minus array of ID's from previous loop (old ID's).

Problem appears at executing second loop.
It seems that i made a mistake at pushing elements into array while inside async function... Some links dont get clicked, but with no scheme, so i assume the problem gets caused by async.

Thank you! Sry if thats not a proper description, thats my first question and i am new to this async world.

```
(async function main() {
   try {

     const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
     const page = await browser.newPage();

     await page.goto('---url---');
     await page.waitForSelector('.cotable');

     const arrIDMaster = [];

     await levelLoop(page, arrIDMaster);
     await levelLoop(page, arrIDMaster);

   } catch (e) {

   }

})();



async function levelLoop(page, arrIDMaster) {

   const rows = await page.$$('.coRow.hi.coTableR');
   const arrIDLocalGet = [];

   //Get all ID's
   for (const row of rows) {
      const rowID = await page.evaluate(el => el.id, row);
      await arrIDLocalGet.push(rowID);
   }

   // First one needs to be removed
   arrIDLocalGet.shift();

   //Create Local ID-Array - difference
   const arrIDLocal = await differenceOf2Arrays(arrIDMaster,arrIDLocalGet);

   // Loop through local ID-Array and Click
   for (const id of arrIDLocal) {
     const rows = await page.$('#' + id);
     const link = await rows.$('a.KnotenLink');
     await link.click();
   }
   //push only new ID's to global array
   for (const id of arrIDLocal) {
     await arrIDMaster.push(id);
   }

   };

function differenceOf2Arrays (array1, array2) {
     return new Promise(resolve => {
       let arrdiff = array2.filter(x => !array1.includes(x));
       resolve(arrdiff);
     });
};
```

Hopefully someone can help me, perhaps it's just a mistake in generell because i am pretty new to this stuff. Beside that i am sure thats not the most beatifull solution, I am also happy for suggestions to this!

Comment: is `arrIDMaster` a plain JS array? if so, then `push` is not async and the `await` on push is unnecessary, maybe even the culprit?

Comment: Yes arrIDMaster is a „plain JS array“, so is arrIDLocal... await didn‘t fix it unfortunately. In fact these arrays seem to be correct (all correct id‘s are in there). I think the problem is somewhere at looping over them!? Do you see a problem there, maby in therm of alternativ syntax? Thx

Comment: I think `differenceOf2Arrays` shouldn't return a promise, you can return the filtered array there.

Comment: I tried it @hardkoded, put unfortunately it wasnt the problem.
I think creating and looping through ID-arrays is correct after logging out everything. I strongly believe that the mistake is somewere at
....    
const rows = await page.$('#' + id);
const link = await rows.$('a.KnotenLink');
....
is "const link = await rows.$('a.KnotenLink');" the correct way to select an anchor link nested somewhere inside the selected const rows? Thx

Comment: Start from there. differenceOf2Arrays shouldn't be async . You don't need to await `arrIDMaster.push(id)`.